# RegEx Pattern that matches positive or negative values (e.g "1.2", "-2.8", "7.8", -22.8")

Tags: java, regex

decimal seperator is a dot, followed by max one digit!
No range specified.

Thanks guys!

Comment: There are different dialects of regular expressions. In which context do you use it?

Comment: I want to use it in Javas String.matches() method

Comment: does it need to match the whole list of numbers or just one decimal number?

Comment: no, I just want to use it on one String that should contain one of these decimal numbers.

Answer (score 17):

```
^-?\d+(\.\d)?$
```

if the decimal part is optional, and

```
^-?\d+\.\d$
```

if it's required :)

Comment: You forgot that dot is a special character.

Comment: Cool, glad it works! :)
Btw, if someone answers your questions, you can "accept" their answer.. Just click on the big green "tick" on the left :)

Comment: I don't think you need the start and end anchors (^$) in String.matches(), though they don't do any harm of course.

Comment: RegEx is powerful when you need it, but very cryptic! All I need is to validate a positive or negative integer, and ended up with `^-?\d+` which works. When I see it, I understand what it does, but to come up with this without having a concrete example that is similar to what I want? not easy...

Comment: @awe don't forget to add a trailing '&' sign in your expression. Otherwise 9lol will be considered a valid integer :)

Comment: @Artiom: Thanks for describing the `&`. Well, I am using this for validating in the ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator, and this validated correctly without the `&`, so this implementation of regex does obviously not require trailing `&` to validate this. Thanks for pointing out though - you could not know that I was using another "dialect" of regex... I just tried your trailing `&` in my regex, and it actually did it wrong (it required a trailing `&` in the string to match...), so obviously the .NET validator does not understand `&` as a special character.

Comment: ...and thanks for providing the answer.. It was your answer here that pointed me in the right direction to solve my validator in the first place. My issue was really to get the `-` sign to be optional, so it was the `?` that did the trick for me compared with what I had first.

Answer (score 7):

Simple: `-?\d+\.\d`

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely to be relevant in this case, but don't forget that "." is not universal as the decimal separator. Many European countries use "," so you might prefer to get the one in use from the locale:

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
String separator = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
```

(See also: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getDecimalSeparator)

Comment: A very valid point, and one that can be a nasty surprise for North American developers.