# HTML5 input pattern decimal with negative values

Tags: regex, html, forms, input

**I have found the following pattern:**

```
\d+(,\d{2})?
```

- It's a regular expression that can be used in HTML5 forms.
- It validates the field to use comma and two decimals.

**It can be used on a text box like this:**

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d+(,\d{2})?" required>
```

**Question**

The pattern works fine except for one thing. It can't handle negative values. How can I modify it to accept negative values?

**Result should be**

- abc - false
- 123 - true
- abc,12 - false
- 123,12 - true
- -123,12 - true
- -123 - true

The last two don't work with the current pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072222/regular-expression-for-positive-and-a-negative-decimal-value-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856226/regex-pattern-that-matches-positive-or-negative-values-e-g-1-2-2-8-7-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749627/javascript-regular-expression-for-negative-numbers-with-decimal

Comment: pattern="-?\d+(,\d{2})?"

Comment: /^-?\d+(,\d{2})?$/gi Same solution as @pawel, but with line anchors to ensure your numbers are not appended/prepended by any unwanted characters.

Comment: You could use  `-?\d+(,\d{2})?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a late answer to your great question!

You could have consider to maybe give a list of chars with a start left boundary <kbd>^</kbd> and then relaxing it from the right, if you wish, and then swipe those chars from left to right which would have likely pass any types of positive and negative numbers including float, with also anything in the right side of the numbers. You could close it with <kbd>$</kbd> which would only allow numbers.

maybe an expression [similar to](https://regex101.com/r/bibfay/1/):

```
^([-+,0-9.]+)
```

[image]

This expression would cover your exampled inputs, but would not work for validating numbers.

If you wish to validate numbers, then you would want to add more boundaries for such instances:

```
+-123
+-,123,12
0.000.000.1
-000,000.0001
+000,000,000,000.1
```

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize your expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = '-123,000,000.19 with anything else that you wish';
 var regex = /^([-+,0-9.]+)(.*)/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `^[+-]?` in the beginning of the pattern. 
So it will be like this: `pattern="^[+-]?\d+(,\d{2})?"`